# uploading videos to youtube or vimeo ( Save link in entry ) possible ?

Tags: file-uploads, uploads

I'm about to make a backend for a contest where people should be able to upload assets(documents,videos,sketches etc ) in their contest entry form.
Is there any smart way to get these videofiles uploaded automaticly to youtube/vimeo rigth/straight from the entry form ?

I know it would be better just to have them provide a video link. Just investergating if any of you know other options (so they dont need to create their own youtubve/vimeo account , and later have all the content one place) ? 
My idea was/is to have a private youtube/vimeo channel for all entry uploads, So they wont be able to see the other videos in the contest before winners are announced.

Anyone done something like this .. hint or guides ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an off the shelf Vimeo or YouTube uploader available currently.

Would you be open to using Amazon S3 for storage? If so, you could use Pixel & Tonic's Assets which allows you to use S3 as a file upload folder.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.
I'll let the question hang a bit.
Wonder if there is any  Amazon S3 youtube/vimeo intergration then. Heard that dropbox has something that uploads videos automaticly on file-uploads. 
Again thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use S3 you don't need youtube. CloudFront even has streaming http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/